# Omit certain fields from being highlighted in Solr

Tags: search, solr, highlight

I have a Solr engine deployed with a Standard Request Handler

```
  <requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
<!-- default values for query parameters -->
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <str name="facet">true</str>
   <str name="facet.field">path</str>
   <str name="facet.sort">lex</str>
   <str name="facet.limit">10</str>
   <str name="facet.offset">0</str>
   <str name="facet.method">fc</str>
   <str name="hl">true</str>
   <str name="hl.fl">body</str>
   <str name="hl.fragsize">888</str>
   <str name="hl.usePhraseHighLighter">true</str>
   <str name="hl.highlightMultiTerm">true</str>
   <str name="hl.mergeContiguous">true</str>
 </lst>
```

Is there a way to omit certain fields from being highlighted, eg. say my query is: `q=Ruth+AND+age:23`.

I only want the search term "Ruth" highlighted, but not the number 23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try expressing the query as: q=Ruth&fq=age:23 since filter queries do not affect highlighting.